# JSON Response parse error from controller

Tags: magento-1, controllers, json, response

Magento 1 - I keep getting a parse error.  I can't figure out where my syntax is wrong.

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
$this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode({"user": true}));
```

This is my ajax request:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".emailfocusout").focusout(function(){
                        var email = $('.emailfocusout').val();
                        console.log('EMAIL: ', email);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/checkout/Email/Email/email/' + email,
                            type: 'POST',
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log('SUCCESS: ', data);
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                console.log('ERROR: ', data);
                            },
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It throws an error because your syntax seems wrong, tries with below syntax

```
$result = ['user'=>true];

$this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($result));
```

Also, I would suggest you to use core Magento function rather then core PHP function,

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

Comment: When I check the Network tab, it still says: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`
I updated the original question with the ajax request.  I trigger the error function with the response.